# Check type received by event emitter

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a strictly typed event emitter for typescript, but I don't know if it is possible.

Supose I create a listener for my emitter:

```
// create listener
@listen('my-custom-event')
function userListener(data: IUser){
  // do something
}
```

Then, I expect typescript check if I am sending a IUser data.

```
// success
myEmitter.emit('my-custom-event', myUser as IUser);

// should return an error
myEmitter.emit('my-custom-event', myNonUser);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. Typescript can check method types in compile time. You should create a map with eventName-type relation. Тake a look at code below.

```
     interface User {
       name: string
     }

     type EmittrMap = {
       'my-custom-event': User;
       'my-custom-event-2': number;
     }

     export class Emitter {
       // some magic line below. It's very useful pattern for inferring method types
       emit<T extends keyof EmittrMap>(eventName: T, arg: EmittrMap[T]) {
         console.log(eventName, arg)
       }
     }

     const myEmitter = new Emitter

     myEmitter.emit('my-custom-event', {name: 'Henry'}) // doesn't fail

     myEmitter.emit('my-custom-event', {age: 10}) // it fails in compile time, 
     // as expected
```

Comment: This works but it needs that I create the type manually. I want to create the type automatically based on @listen decorator.

Comment: mayby you can generate this map from decorators using  https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph

But it's not simple. And I don't think one should.
You'll get problems with conflicting types  applying the same decorator to listeners with  different signature